# getting json object instead of json array in php

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

I want the result for the `json_encode()` as an array for example this:

```
[
   {
      "url":"http://localhost/.....",
      "name":"abc"
   },
   {
      "url":"http://localhost/.....",
      "name":"xyz"
   },
]
```

But I'm getting the result as an object as this :

```
{"images":[{"url":"http:\/\/192.168.0.100\/1.JPG","name":"abc"},{"url":"http:\/\/192.168.0.100\/2.JPG","name":"xyz"}]}
```

php code:

```
<?php 

//Importing dbdetails file 
 require_once 'dbDetails.php';

 //connection to database 
 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');

 //sql query to fetch all images 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";

 //getting images 
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 //response array 
 $response = array();  
 $response['images'] = array(); 

 //traversing through all the rows 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 $temp = array(); 
 $temp['url']=$row['url'];
 $temp['name']=$row['name'];
 array_push($response['images'],$temp);

 }

 //displaying the response 
 echo json_encode($response);
```

I have tried using array_values as this:

```
 echo json_encode(array_values($response));
```

But it results in an html code appended before the json string...

Comment: i see no problem here.. if you print value of `youJSONObject['images']`, You'll get your desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it like this:-

```
 $response = array();  
 //$response['images'] = array();  not needed

 //traversing through all the rows 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ //since you are using name indexes so use _assoc()
   $temp = array(); 
   $temp['url']=$row['url'];
   $temp['name']=$row['name'];
   $response[] =$temp;
 }

 //displaying the response 
 echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how could I fetch the content in the array in Descending order of the field 'id'?

Comment: Please ask a new question by showing your input array and what code you tried so for to get your desired output.Thanks